# (Server app) windows form not appearing on load

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

I am trying to implement a simple TCP/IP communication inside of an existing windows form application.  The code that makes up the communication part has an infinite while loop that I believe makes the server constantly listen for clients.  It works fine for my application, except I am a little stuck on how to make it run on a seperate thread.  I will post my code below:

```
private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        startServer();

    }

private void startServer()
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        serverSocket.Start();

        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {

                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                listBox1.Items.Add(" >> Data from client - " + dataFromClient);
                string serverResponse = "Server acknowledges the request - " + dataFromClient;
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Flush();
                listBox1.Items.Add(" >> " + serverResponse);


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }



        }
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice on this issue.  Thank you!

Comment: Drop a BackgroundWorker on your form.  Press F1 to get help.

Comment: You forgot to implement a protocol, so the behavior of this code is going to be unpredictable. TCP has no notion of a message, so if you need application-level messages, *you* have to implement them.

Comment: David, I was simply going to send strings back and forth in a particular form and then run those through conditional statements on the server side to detect what to do.  I just chose 10025 bytes from this example.  Does bytesFrom shape the protocol at all?

Comment: @user1197993: You need a protocol to do that. How does the server know when it has a complete message? Your conditional statements will act unpredictably if you don't design and implement an application messaging protocol.

Comment: I still don't understand.  Could you provide an answer that shows something to maybe go off of for implementing a protocol?  Right now for the complete message I have the server check up to a dollar sign '$' that gets appended at the end of the string the client sends.  I look forward to your reply, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a BackgroundWorker and call your server in the "DoWork" method, something like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        startServer() // Call here what you want to execute in another thread
    }
    }

}
```

You can see it more detailed [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Allow me to try this out.

Comment: Elvin, this is the error i get when i try using a background worker:  "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"

Comment: It seems like another process is using that port. First ensure that just start the server once. Second you can check if any firewall is blocking your process. 

Also you can check the port's status using telnet 127.0.0.1 8888.

What is the purpose for your server? practice? otherwise i strongly suggest you consider the WCF Services. They will help you to avoid the 'dirty' job and they can be perfectly hosted like a service listening at any port, still without talk about the available protocols.

Comment: Well it works when I don't use a background worker, but then I don't get the functionality of all the other stuff in my windows form because of that infinite loop at form load.  The server portion needs to be running whenever the form is showing so thats where I decided to put it.  You are right I will need to make sure the IP address never changes because this will be a company software project for a client.  Also to answer your questions, I am actually using the computer's IP address which is 10.1.6.130 rather than localhost.  And yes there are no firewalls blocking.